# Is there any difference between conditional batch normalization and batch normalization except the usage of MLPs for predicting $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Tags: comparison, batch-normalization

Batch normalization in neural networks uses $\beta$ and $\gamma$ for scaling. The analytical formula is given by

$$\dfrac{x - \mathbb{E}[x]}{\sqrt{Var(X)}}* \gamma + \beta$$

Conditional batch normalization uses multi-layer perceptrons to calculate the values of $\gamma$ and $\beta$ instead of giving fixed values to them.

Is it only the difference between them or is there any other fundamental difference between them in terms of functionality?

Comment: Is [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00683v3.pdf) the paper that talks about this conditional BN you're referring to?

Comment: @nbro Yes. I think the same is found in the PyTorch option for normalization with affine = True option. But... Yeah... The same paper...